# Is it possible to create a file that never completes its download process?

Tags: http

Is it possible to built a file from scratch that when it gets downloaded via HTTP, the download never actually completes ? I am not talking about ZIP BOMB here.

Some download software allows you to download streaming events, thus the final size of the file is not known. Is it possible to craft a file where the download software is not able to "guess" the actual file size and keeps on downloading?

Comment: The download software never "guesses" the file size. When a file transfer is initiated the server sends some header information and in that header info the download software is told how big the file will be before it starts downloading. It is quite easy to misconfigure a server to not announce the file's size and simply send a file to be downloaded so your download software will just keep downloading until the server stops sending.

Comment: Could you draw a line between the definition of download and stream? A file download is, to me, finite; while a stream runs until I tell it to stop. I can't tell if you're mincing terms on accident.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus:  A server is not necessarily misconfigured if it can't tell how large the response is.    It might literally not know, that's why there is `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.  (You could argue that the server could just buffer the output from CGIs, but let's not.)

Comment: yes: https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview ;)

Comment: @OskarSkog True, but my main point still stands. The download software doesn't guess, it gets told.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus At least firefox seems to only treat the announced size as hint. When the server gracefully closes the connection and less than the announced size has been downloaded it considers the download successful. (That's very annoying when using SOCKS proxies, since those turn connection loss into gracefully closed connections, resulting in silently truncated downloads)

Comment: This question is incredibly vague. You're probably not talking about "creating a file", but it's hard to tell what you actually mean.

Comment: So many different ways to do this, the question is actually poor. A file is simply an arbitrary chunk of data which could easily be concurrently modified to produce your desired result.

Comment: I'm missing something. What does this have to do with information security?

Comment: @PaulDraper the concept can be used as a denial-of-service: keeping a connection open and forcing a client to fill its memory/disk with junk.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  You just need to use the chunked transfer encoding.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Depending on your server's configuration, you might be able to simply create a CGI script that writes and flushes stdout in an infinite loop.

It does not seem to work on Lighttpd which I believe buffers the entire output from the CGI script before sending it to the client.  It might work on other webservers though.

Example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
Transfer-Encoding: chunked\r\n
Content-Type: text/plain\r\n
\r\n
1e\r\n
Uh-oh, this will never stop.\n
1e\r\n
Uh-oh, this will never stop.\n
```

followed by an infinite repetition of "1e\r\nUh-oh, this will never stop.\n"

Comment: Do you really *need* the chunked transfer encoding? Why wouldn't sending lots of data (and throttling it, if desired) not be possible without chunks?

Comment: @CL. otherwise the browser expects to get a Content-Length header and will discard any data beyond that length, so it can't be infinite.

Comment: AFAIK browsers do not actually expect it in all cases: [Is the Content-Length header required for a HTTP/1.0 response?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15991173/11654)

Comment: With HTTP/1.0 the request ends with eof  *OR* the length defined by the *optional* content-length header. With HTTP/1.1 both options still exist and additionally there is chunked transfer encoding.

Comment: HTTP 1.1 [says](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) that Content-Length  "SHOULD be sent whenever the message's length can be determined prior to being transferred".

Answer (score 15):

Yes, just stream /dev/urandom to the client. First, maybe you'll need to fake the file header, so that client thinks it's downloading the stuff it requested, and after that just stream random junk.

An idea on how to do this in Python:

```
with open("/dev/random", 'rb') as f:
    print repr(f.read(10))
```

Comment: Also don't forget to actually use urandom in the code so it won't block while refilling the entropy pool.

Comment: @OskarSkog: Manual flushing is not necessary, the buffer is not very large and will automatically get flushed when it fills.

Comment: If all you're trying is a basic DOS, just use zeroes.

Answer (score 5):

If the output is dynamically generated by the server software, it is possible to create a stream that keeps going on until you break the connection. However if you literally want a file it cannot be infinite in size.

However if your file system supports sparse files you can create a file that is larger than the storage media and that way produce a file which would take such a long time to download that it isn't feasible to download it all.

The maximum file size differs between file systems. On ext4 the limit is 16TB. On tmpfs the limit is 8EB. Here is a couple of examples on how such files could be created:

```
dd if=/dev/null of=/dev/shm/sparse bs=1 seek=7E
dd if=/dev/null of=/tmp/sparse bs=1 seek=15T
```

Beware when putting such files on a webserver. If the server software you are using doesn't throttle the bandwidth it is possible for a malicious client to overload your network.

Comment: A way to create sparse files that is easier to remember: `truncate -s15T /tmp/sparse`